# Angular 8 : ngx-socket-io rewrites connection url when running in prod mode

Tags: node.js, angular, socket.io

Basically, the problem is that in dev mode the socket client connects to `http://localhost:3002/socket.io/?EIO=3&transport=polling&t=N4--_Ms` and everything works.

But when I run the app in prod mode, the url becomes `http://localhost/?EIO=3&transport=polling&t=N4--_Ms` which throws a 404 error.

I'd like to understand why and of course a fix if anyone can help.

I use `"ngx-socket-io": "^3.0.1"` and here's the configuration in `app.modules.ts`

```
const ioConfig: SocketIoConfig = { url: "http://localhost:3002/socket.io", options: { secure: true, rejectUnauthorized: false } };

@NgModule({
  declarations: [
     AppComponent,
  ],
  imports: [
     AppRouting,
     BrowserModule,
     BrowserAnimationsModule,
     SocketIoModule.forRoot(ioConfig)
  ],
  providers: [],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
export class AppModule { }
```

The socket.io server is attached to an express backend at `localhost:3002`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solved it by using the service version instead of registering `SocketIoModule` in AppModule as per [documentation in npm](https://www.npmjs.com/package/ngx-socket-io#using-multiple-sockets-with-different-end-points).

Answer (score 2):

I think what you are looking for is the "path:string" option in the SocketIOConfig argument.

I am using Nginx to reverse proxy into a NodeJS server, so I also experienced path truncation with this code in app.module.ts :

```
SocketIoModule.forRoot({ url: 'wss://localhost:9000/SomeUniqueEndpoint/', options: { transports: ['websocket'], allowUpgrades : true} })
```

I would check the path and it would just say "wss://localhost:9000" ... 404 not found.

Instead do this in app.module.ts

```
SocketIoModule.forRoot({ url: 'wss://' + document.location.host , options: { transports: ['websocket'], allowUpgrades : true, path: '/SomeUniqueEndpoint/socket.io' } })
```